# How to parse System.Collections.Generic.List in jquery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0

I am using a jquery to call a collection 
Suppose this is my collection

```
        PageBL pageBL = new PageBL();
        List<Page> pageList = pageBL.GetCategoryPageList(categoryID);
        return pageList;
```

I am getting this list in jquery,

```
$.get("/Home/GetActionMethod/" + id, { CategoryID: id }, function (data) {

            });
```

Now can any one tell me how this data is parsed so that I get the required result.

Comment: each Page object will be in a javascript array .

Comment: i am assuming that this is the `controller` code ... what is the `View` code ?

Comment: @dan_l ok it will be treated as javascript array ,Thanks.

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli the view code is the jquery code which i have given second

Comment: `I am using a jquery to call a collection` => this sentence makes no sense. jQuery doesn't know anything about collections. You are probably using jQuery to send an AJAX request to a controller action which returns some action result (ViewResult, JsonResult, FileResult, some custom result, ...). So the question is: how does this controller action look like and what result does it return? Once we know that we can more easily help you with the parsing on the client side.

Comment: Yes you are right. I am making a ajax call to the controller and the controller returns the List<SampleObject>. This collection i am receiving in jquery,And now I have to parse the Collection to retrive my actual data The Actual Problem was this.
But Then I have changed the collection into a string in the controller And By using the split function in jquery I have received the actual result.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `return Json(pageList);` in your controller action,

The format will depend on the `Page` layout. But something like:

```
[
    {"PageName": "Title", "SomeOtherProp": "Value"}, 
    {"PageName": "Some other page", "SomeOtherProp": "Value2"}
]
```

`PageName` and `SomeOtherProp` correspond to properties in the `Page` class

To traverse the information and handle it you can just do:

```
$.get("/Home/GetCategoryPageList/" + id, { CategoryID: id }, function (data) {
    $.each(data, function(item) {
        alert('Property from an item: ' + item.PageName);
    });
});
```

Comment: no actually i am sendign whole collection of my database table data in that collection that is why i am not using JSON

Answer (score 0):

Please read my topic already opened, it might help you
[Return a JSon array to $.ajax from ActionResult type method in MVC 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7963610/return-a-json-array-to-ajax-from-actionresult-type-method-in-mvc-3)

or

```
var data=null;
$.ajax({
         url: '/Home/GetCategoryPageList/',
         dataType: 'json',
         contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
         data: {CategoryID: id}
         success: function (msg) {
            data = msg;
         },
         complete: function () {
           //do something with data
           $.each(data, function(index, value)
           { 
             $("#div1").append(value.PageName); //or other property from generic list
            } 
         }
      });
```

I'm assuming that you have a generic list which contains jgauffin structure (PageName, Title, SomeOtherProp, etc.)

in your controller

```
PageBL pageBL = new PageBL();
        List<Page> pageList = pageBL.GetCategoryPageList(categoryID);
        return this.Json( new {
         msg = pageList
      });
```

Comment: $.get (which $.ajax uses) will automatically detect json as type, no need to specify it.